# How to mutate items of a vector during iteration?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, borrow-checker, mutability

I have a `Vec` of structs. When iterating over this `Vec` using `.iter()` I want to edit each element inside a `for` loop, but I'm getting an error that says each element is already borrowed, how can I solve this? Here's a small code example:

```rust
struct complex_struct {
    attr1: i32
}
    
let elements: Vec<complex_struct> = generate_data();
    
for element in elements.iter() {
    element.attr1 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter_mut) to get mutable elements out of the iterator:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct ComplexStruct {
    attr1: i32
}

fn main() {
    let mut elements: Vec<ComplexStruct> = vec![ComplexStruct { attr1: 5 }];

    for element in elements.iter_mut() {
        element.attr1 = 0;
    }
    
    dbg!(elements); // prints out [ComplexStruct { attr1: 0 }]
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af9fada8e195b6f1558e27d2d1a8e8a4)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i need.